# Empty gridlines in android gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, gridlines

I want a gridview with empty grid lines as follows

[image: Gridlines in Empty Cells]

Here is what i got till now, gridview with gridlines in the occupied cells only. I want gridlines in empty cells also. Is this possible?

[image: Gridline in Occupied Cells]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost positive a GridView was never intended for this, so you have two options.

-Write your own GridView that supports a defaulted view.

OR

-If this is not a dynamic view that is changing all the time in real time:

1. In your adapter, set a minimum in your getCount method (return Math.max(actualSize, minimumCount)).  And set the views with no data to your empty boxes.
2. Make sure the count is always some mod of 4 to ensure each row will be filled beyond that.

That's just what I'm coming up with on the top of my head, there's most likely a better way to do it, but hopefully I'm moving you in the right direction.

Comment: @Romano thanks man, i had the second option in my mind. However i just want to know if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an empy `View` within the empty cells of the grid.
For example, use a `TextView` with no text, or simply a `new View()`.